# mariadb failed to start

Tags: mariadb, rhel, rhel8

I never had this problem before, i already have one server i just run:

```
yum -y install mariadb-server
systemctl start mariadb
mysql_secure_installation
```

After that everything works fine.

BUT, on this system process called **mysql-prepare-db-dir** returns an error code because **dirname: missing operand** and **Database MariaDB is not initialized, but the directory is not empty, so initialization cannot be done.**

Command systemctl status mariadb.service -l gives me this output:

```
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-07-19 17:11:19 CEST; 47s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 47091 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mysql-prepare-db-dir mariadb.service (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 47088 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mysql-check-socket (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 19 17:11:19 linuxbox systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3 database server...
Jul 19 17:11:19 linuxbox mysql-prepare-db-dir[47091]: dirname: missing operand
Jul 19 17:11:19 linuxbox mysql-prepare-db-dir[47091]: Try 'dirname --help' for more information.
Jul 19 17:11:19 linuxbox mysql-prepare-db-dir[47091]: /usr/libexec/mysql-prepare-db-dir[6]: source: /mysql-scripts-common: No such file or directory
Jul 19 17:11:19 linuxbox mysql-prepare-db-dir[47091]: Database MariaDB is not initialized, but the directory  is not empty, so initialization cannot be done.
Jul 19 17:11:20 linuxbox mysql-prepare-db-dir[47091]: Make sure the  is empty before running mysql-prepare-db-dir.
Jul 19 17:11:19 linuxbox systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 19 17:11:19 linuxbox systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 19 17:11:20 linuxbox systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3 database server.
```

The system i am experiencing this problem is installed on a generic desktop, for developing practice purposes i want LAMP stack installed. I don't know what am i doing wrong.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I wanna help you to troubleshooting.

1. You can install MariaDB Server from the command-line:

```
$ sudo yum install mariadb-server
```

2. After installing the packages, run the `mysql_install_db` utility to provision this directory.

```
$ sudo mysql_install_db
```

3. Start the `systemd`  service for MariaDB Server using `systemctl`:

```
$ sudo systemctl start mariadb.service
```

4. Some basic steps should be taken to help harden the MariaDB Community Server deployment:

```
$ sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

From the output you share with us and from step-by-step it looks you missed one step (#2) :

```
$ sudo mysql_install_db
```

Have fun!